# Build dataframe with sequential timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains many timestamps associated with different ships and ports.

```
   obj_id   timestamp   port
0  4        2019-10-01  Houston    
1  2        2019-09-01  New York 
2  4        2019-07-31  Boston   
3  1        2019-07-28  San Francisco
4  2        2019-10-15  Miami
5  1        2019-09-01  Honolulu
6  1        2019-08-01  Tokyo
```

I want to build a dataframe that contains a single record for the latest voyage by ship (obj_id), by assigning the latest timestamp/port for each obj_id as a 'destination', and the second latest timestamp/port as the 'origin'. So the final result would look something like this:

```
   obj_id   origin_time origin_port     destination_time   destination_port
0  4        2019-07-31  Boston          2019-10-01         Houston
1  2        2019-09-01  New York        2019-10-15         Miami
3  1        2019-07-28  Tokyo            2019-09-01         Honolulu
```

I've successfully filtered the latest timestamps for each obj_id through this code but still can't figure a way to filter the *second* latest timestamp, let alone pull them both into a single row.

```
df.sort_values(by ='timestamp', ascending = False).drop_duplicates(['obj_id'])
```

Comment: Nice first question, although I do believe that there's an error in your example output. Isn't the last trip for ship #1 from Tokyo to Honolulu rather than San Francisco to Honolulu?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out orlp, quickly typed out dummy data for sake of example. Fixed that in the question

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby.agg` with `first, last`:

```
dfg = df.sort_values('timestamp').groupby('obj_id').agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index()
dfg.columns = [f'{c1}_{c2}' for c1, c2 in dfg.columns]

   obj_id_ timestamp_first timestamp_last     port_first port_last
0        1      2019-07-28     2019-09-01  San Francisco  Honolulu
1        2      2019-09-01     2019-10-15       New York     Miami
2        4      2019-07-31     2019-10-01         Boston   Houston
```

Comment: First/last is not correct, the question states there might be many voyages in the database.

Comment: That's what `sort_values` in combination with `first/last` fixes for us. This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort the trips by timestamp so we can get the most recent voyages, then group the voyages by object id and grab the first and second voyage per object, then merge.

```
groups = df.sort_values(by = "timestamp", ascending = False).groupby("obj_id")
pd.merge(groups.nth(1), groups.nth(0),
         on="obj_id",
         suffixes=("_origin", "_dest"))
```

Make sure your timestamp column is the proper timestamp data type though, otherwise your sorting will be messed up.

Comment: Don't need necessarily to be in timestamp data type, as long as it is `YYYY-MM-DD` it'll be fine ;) (also works for integers YYYYMMDD). - of course, best practices is to have dt though